# Method not found using Monero JSON-RPC in PHP

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, php

`Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Request have return error: Method not found; Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getblockcount","params":null,"id":1}; in jsonRPCClient.php:166`

I don't know what to do. I started monero-wallet-rpc on the port and configured the example.php with port, localhost, username and password.
First I was running with no-rpc-auth and it gave me same error, then I deleted that argument and launched and told me unauthorized, then I edited the example.php and same error is up.
I also launched monerod in screen.

Answer (score 1):

getblockcount is a daemon RPC, but you mention monero-wallet-rpc mostly. It is likely you are trying to call this RPC on the wallet, not on the daemon, and the wallet rightfully errors out.

Comment: This is the right answer. It's not an authorization problem, the `getblockcount` method just doesn't exist on the wallet RPC, only on the [daemon RPC](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_count)

Answer (score 0):

Try params:{} maybe.

This one works for me:

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:28081/json_rpc -d 
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"getblockcount","params":{}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`


`{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "count": 1097471,
    "status": "OK"
  }`

Comment: I tried if params = null, then params = {} but didn't work.
Request have return error: Method not found; Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getblockcount","params":"{}","id":1}

Comment: Are you sure you're conneting to the right URL (/json_rpc), the right server/port ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `"id": "0"` instead of `"id": "1"`
From the [deamon RPC dev guide](https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block_count) (up to date):

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block_count"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  

{  
  "id": "0",  
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",  
  "result": {  
    "count": 993163,  
    "status": "OK"  
  }  
}
```

I ran it successfully when i did the update. So either the **id** field or the server you try to connect to is your problem.
Are you using both `--confirm-external-bind` and `--rpc-bind-ip 0.0.0.0` on your monderod?